# Code coverage in VS2013 show coverage of Test and not actual code

Tags: visual-studio-2013, code-coverage, mstest

I am following article for code coverage in *VS 2013* http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537628.aspx. It shows coverage of Test and not actual code.

I have selected unit test from *Test explorer* and click on `Analyze Code Coverage -> Selected Test`. Code coverage window is opened up at the bottom and It shows dll of unit test and its coverage and actual dll with code coverage is not shown.

Also, I looked into article http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj159523.aspx. Copied pdbs and dll into same location. In the code coverage window message was

> Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731"

*Any idea about this?*

Comment: Please care to comment before downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried steps given in the link.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/allendm/archive/2012/09/08/empty-coverage-file-with-profiler-related-errors-in-the-event-logs.aspx

Slight change if you are using VS 2013.

a) Environment variable VS120COMNTOOLS is set to \common7\tools

b) Regkey HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\InstallDir is set to your \Common7\IDE\

c) covrun32.dll and covrun64.dll exist in "\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage"

Removed VS110COMNTOOLS environment variable. These changes worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve my issue. The reason why code coverage was not happening on my production DLL was: reason = "has_fixed_base". Once I changed this setting to: Yes (`/DYNAMICBASE`), the coverage started working.

It would help to check these steps:

1. Open Project Properties
2. go to `Linker->Advanced` page
3. In that, check `Randomized Base Address`
4. Change it to Yes (`/DYNAMICBASE`)

This should start code coverage.