# How to publish Code coverage result back to TFS 2013

Tags: tfs, code-coverage

**Scenario:**

We're trying to enable code coverage in our TFS and so far the build summary result was successfully displaying code blocks covered as shown in picture below but the problem is every time we click **Coverage Results** link (arrow down in the picture) it doesn't shown the details of what has been covered and it display error in the browser even the test results In/Out folder have code coverage file in build server.

**Setup:**

[image]

**MSTest Settings (Local.testsetting)**

[image]

**Test Run**

[image]

**Build Definition**
[image]

**Test Results**
[image]

**Build Summary:**

[image]

**After clicking Coverage Results:**
[image]

**Question :** Why TFS 2013 project collection **Coverage Results link** (red arrow down) in build summary doesn't display code coverage details of what has been covered even the code coverage file was generated in build server TFS 2010? What do we missed in the settings to make it possible?

Comment: It's nice to have a comment why the question has been down voted to improve question rather than just leaving with down vote.

Comment: Did the link opened correctly if you are using build server 2013?

Comment: Are you using a custom template? There should be code coverage option for Test in Default Template.

Comment: May be yes, I'm not the one who setup the build template.

Answer (score 1):

You need to
1). open the build definition, go to **Process** -> **3.Test** -> **Automated Test** -> on the **Add/Edit Test Run** dialog, set the **Options** to be "**Enable Code Coverage**".
2). Select the .testsettings file in the build definition.

[image]

You can also  to have a check on *Ralph Jansen's* reply in this question [TFS 2013 - No Code Coverage Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016217/tfs-2013-no-code-coverage-results)

Moreover, also check could you open this code coverage link in web portal.

---

**Update**

*add related screenshot*

[image]

Comment: Thank you for you're answer but as you can see in my **Test Run** picture there is no drop-down option to choose **Enable Code Coverage**. Enabling of Code Coverage was set on Test Setting pane (see my picture).

Comment: @JrTabuloc It's not in the drop down, You need to click a button with `..` at  the left of the bar. Details you can see my update screenshot.

Comment: I don't have that option. I'm using VS 2013 Ultimate. See my Build Definition Picture you will notice that I don't have that. May be we're using custom build template?

Comment: Sorry for the later reply, you can try to use this [extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/86a239cf-b0e3-4af4-a6a2-319b135867c0)  which allows you to update the default build process template used when creating a new build definition. Then try it again.